# Transform an image with projection EPSG:4326 to EPSG:3857

Tags: gdal, coordinate-system, leaflet, gdalwarp, gdal-translate

I have an image with known boundary and projection EPSG:4326 and want to overlay it to openstreetmap using Leaflet.js.

I have tried using function imageoverlay, but the image is not aligned with the basemap.

```
L.imageOverlay(imgUrl, [[-15, 75], [45, 145]], {opacity: 0.6, autoZIndex: true});
```

So, I use gdalwarp to transform the image projection to EPSG:3857.

```
gdal_translate -of Gtiff -a_ullr -15 145 45 75 -a_srs EPSG:4326 test.png out_4326.tiff
gdalwarp -s_srs EPSG:4326 -t_srs EPSG:3857 -ts 850 728 out_4326.tiff out_3857.tiff
gdal_translate -of png out_3857.tiff final.png
```

However, the final image looks like distorted. Here is the original image. 
[image]

Here is the final image
[image]

Comment: You should just be able to use http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#imageoverlay for that, since you already have the bounding box. What have you already tried and what didn't work for you?

Comment: @BradHards I want to use simple basemap like openstreetmap which projection is in Web Mercator (EPSG:3857). Do you have any tile source which is is EPSG:4326 so that I can use with leaflet ?

Comment: What have you already tried? If your image isn't very big, the warping won't be significant and you can probably just use the imageoverlay method on a 3857 base map.

Comment: @BradHards Ya I tried imageoverlay and the image is not aligned with basemap. The range is quite big. L.imageOverlay(imgUrl, [[-15, 75], [45, 145]], {opacity: 0.6, autoZIndex: true});

Comment: That that would have been really useful information to put in the question, along with what else you've already tried (e.g. gdalwarp offline first).

Comment: @BradHards gdapwarp can help? Let me try!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gdal_translate expects the extent in the format `-a_ullr ulx uly lrx lry`. Form the picture I guess you swapped x (Easting) and y (Northing), and upper left and lower right.

I get the right picture with:

```
gdal_translate -of Gtiff -a_ullr 75 45 145 -15 -a_srs EPSG:4326 CJGMY.png out_4326.tiff
gdalwarp -s_srs EPSG:4326 -t_srs EPSG:3857 -ts 850 728 out_4326.tiff out_3857.tiff
gdal_translate -of png out_3857.tiff final.png
```

fitting to Openstreetmap background:

[image]

For the correct leaflet syntax, see http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#imageoverlay

```
var imageUrl = 'http://www.lib.utexas.edu/maps/historical/newark_nj_1922.jpg',
imageBounds = [[40.712216, -74.22655], [40.773941, -74.12544]];
```

For an image of Newark NJ, this seems to be lower left, upper right in Northing-Easting order.