# Convert image from one EPSG defined CRS to another

Tags: coordinate-system, convert, image, epsg

I've got a lot of image files (.png or .jpg) that I want to convert from one EPSG defined CRS system to another, e.g. from [EPSG:31255](http://www.epsg-registry.org/export.htm?wkt=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::31255) to [EPSG:25833](http://www.epsg-registry.org/export.htm?wkt=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::25833), on a server within a Java app.

For each image I know the coordinates (x,y) of the lower left and upper right corner in that specific CRS system.

What I've found so far:

- QGIS: Is able to do this but I'd have to do it by hand ([answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/208862/148791))
- [GDAL](https://gdal.org/programs/gdalwarp.html): Is able to convert images but it uses C++ (which I can't use on the server)
- [Proj4js](http://proj4js.org/): Can only convert coordinates
- Geotools: I've only found information about converting [coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6023242/2016165) or full [shapefiles](https://docs.geotools.org/stable/tutorials/geometry/geometrycrs.html) so far.

Can GeoTools convert images too or what other Java/JavaScript library can?

**Edit:**

I'm currently using version 22.2 of GeoTools. The dependencies in the pom.xml file are:

- junit
- gt-shapefile
- gt-swing
- gt-geotiff
- gt-image (not sure if I need that one)
- gt-epsg-hsql

The imports in the java file are:

- import org.geotools.coverage.grid.GridCoverage2D;
- import org.geotools.coverage.grid.io.AbstractGridCoverage2DReader;
- import org.geotools.coverage.grid.io.AbstractGridFormat;
- import org.geotools.coverage.grid.io.GridFormatFinder;
- import org.geotools.coverage.processing.Operations;
- import org.geotools.gce.geotiff.GeoTiffFormat;
- import org.geotools.gce.geotiff.GeoTiffWriter;
- import org.geotools.referencing.CRS;
- import org.geotools.util.factory.Hints;
- import org.opengis.referencing.crs.CoordinateReferenceSystem;

Comment: are they images or raster data (with a .wld file)? or could you construct a .wld file for them?

Comment: @IanTurton They are images but I can generate the according .jgw/.pgw files if necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a matching `.wld` and `.prj` file then the [gt-image](https://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/coverage/image.html) module can read and write jpeg and png files.

Once you've read the file in to a `GridCoverage` you can reproject it and write it out with no difficulty:

```
AbstractGridFormat format = GridFormatFinder.findFormat(input);
Hints hints = null;
if (format instanceof GeoTiffFormat) {
  hints = new Hints(Hints.FORCE_LONGITUDE_FIRST_AXIS_ORDER, Boolean.TRUE);
}

AbstractGridCoverage2DReader reader = format.getReader(input, hints);
GridCoverage2D coverage = reader.read(null);
reader.dispose();
GridCoverage2D coverageTransf = (GridCoverage2D) Operations.DEFAULT.resample(coverage, targetCRS);

GeoTiffFormat outFormat = new GeoTiffFormat();
GridCoverageWriter writer = outFormat.getWriter(destFile, hints);
writer.write(coverageTransf, null);
writer.dispose();
```

Assuming your input image is in `input`, your target CRS is in `targetCRS` and the output file is in `destFile`.

PS: see [my blog post](https://blog.ianturton.com/geotools,/projections,/itches/2017/10/20/adding-prj.html) on how to add a `.prj` file to a lot of world images if they are missing.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103803/discussion-on-answer-by-ian-turton-convert-image-from-one-epsg-defined-crs-to-an).

Answer (score 0):

Some additional information:

To get the code in Ian Turton's answer (GeoTools 22.2, Java 8) to run properly I had to add the following dependencies to the `pom.xml` file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
    <artifactId>gt-geotiff</artifactId>
    <version>${geotools.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
    <artifactId>gt-image</artifactId>
    <version>${geotools.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
    <artifactId>gt-epsg-hsql</artifactId>
    <version>${geotools.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Why?:

- *gt-geotiff*: Used for `GeoTiffFormat` (Error: `GeoTiffFormat cannot be resolved to a type`)
- *gt-image*: Without you'll get `Trying to get a reader from an unknown format.` with `AbstractGridCoverage2DReader reader = format.getReader(input, hints)`
- *gt-epsg-hsql*: Otherwise you'll get: `org.opengis.referencing.NoSuchAuthorityCodeException: No code "EPSG:25833" from authority "EPSG" found for object of type "EngineeringCRS".`
- I also added `gt-coverage` at first but the app seems to run fine without it.

I also had to get rid of the `Hints.FORCE_LONGITUDE_FIRST_AXIS_ORDER` hint, otherwise the output images would all be mirrored and rotated by 90°. This does seem to depend on the used .prj file:

The file (for "EPSG:31255") I downloaded  from [epsg.io](http://epsg.io) (use the "Well Known Text as HTML" export and rename!) works fine as it includes "TOWGS84". The .prj file I got from [spatialreference.org](http://spatialreference.org) also includes that code but still produces a wrong result (didn't test their "WKT as HTML" version though).